# Find first non-zero value index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays:

```
[
    [0,0],
    [0,0],
    [3,2],
    [5,6],
    [15,9],
    [0,0],
    [7,23],
]
```

I could use something like `.indexOf(0)` if I wanted to find first zero value index, but how do I find index of the first non-zero value or which conforms to some criteria?

It might look like `.indexOf(function(val){ return val[0] > 0 || val[1] > 0;})`, but this one is not supported.

How do I tackle this problem in the most elegant way?

Comment: If I understand correctly, with your example it should give 2 ?

Comment: You can use Array#some with a side effect in the callback to give you the index

Comment: ES6 offers [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How do I tackle this problem in the most elegant way?

The best solution is to use native ES6 array method `.findIndex` (or Lodash/Underscore `_.findIndex`).

```
var index = yourArr.findIndex(val=>val[0] > 0 || val[1] > 0)
```

This code uses ES6 arrow function and is equivalent to:

```
var index = yourArr.findIndex(function (val) {
  return val[0] > 0 || val[1] > 0;
});
```

You can of course use `.some` method to retrieve index, but this solution isn't elegant.

Further reference about `.find`, `.findIndex` and arrow functions:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

You may have to shim `Array#findIndex` if not there, but that's easily done.

Comment: "how do I find **index** of the first non-zero value" -> It should be `.findIndex()` instead of `.find()`

Comment: No need to call out `some` as being inelegant. Might as well call out `forEach` and `reduce` and a simple loop and...

Comment: @Andreas: Doh! It should be `findIndex`, not `find`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it doesnt seem that `findIndex` is widely supported just yet https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex ... I wish you would undelete your answer because that is elegant for es5 standards

Comment: @AmmarCSE: True that support isn't broad yet, but it's easily shimmed (with `Array#some`, potentially) and it's for *exactly* this use case, so...

Comment: Shimming! I forgot about that nice little approach :)